# jQuery! I fail to use _.debounce properly

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, debouncing

I'm trying to use the function [_.debounce()](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) of [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) but I can't do it properly.

I'm trying to debounce the scroll of my window as shown below, but I am seriously confused.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrollCounter = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollCounter > 0 ) { //do stuff }
    else { //do stuff }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hey man, I saw your recent deleted question. That question is **not** a right question to ask here. See what to to ask and what not to ask in Stack Overflow. And also [ask] page. It is like you are asking a chef, what should I do to get my tonsilitis removed.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation and example:

```
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
$(window).resize(lazyLayout);
```

you can refactor your call to debounce it like this:

```
function scrollHandler() {
    var scrollCounter = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollCounter > 0 ) { /* do stuff /* }
    else { /* do stuff */ }
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    var debouncedScroll = _.debounce(scrollHandler, 50);
    $(window).scroll(debouncedScroll);

});
```

---

**Update**: Working jsfilddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/z635f7ys/

Comment: Sorry I misclicked. I've minor edited your answer to be able to revert.

Comment: I didn't downvote. It doesn't work though but it seems right. That's weird.

Comment: @baao thanks - that code was direct copy from OPs code

Comment: @Diprap I've added a working jsfiddle - make sure you have the console open, then drag the scroll bar down, pausing slightly on the way.  You should get multiple "scroll" logs, then one "scroll handler" log when you pause/stop.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you a lot sir.